# Java 8. Math.ceil() function description

Tags: java, math, documentation

I do see following description (in docs) for the function Math.ceil(double a):

> Returns the smallest (closest to negative infinity) double value that
> is greater than or equal to the argument and is equal to a
> mathematical integer.

Do I something miss or it is incorrect in here "Returns the smallest (closest to negative infinity)"?
I mean, when you do use it, whatever not zero number there will be after decimal point, it will always be upped in positive direction, not negative (so it returns closest to positive infinity).

Comment: The statement is correct. `it will always be upped in positive direction` Yeah, thats what it says: "Returns the smallest (closest to negative infinity) double value __that is greater than or equal to the argument__ and is equal to a mathematical integer."

Comment: You can't just take take an isolated part of the description and treat it like the rest doesn't exist. Of course if the description says "returns number that fulfills X and also fulfills Y" and you only look at "returns number that fulfills X" you're likely to get a wrong result.

Comment: But this is not the isolated part of description. It's a complete short description.
You can take a look at it here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil-double-
I mean for what is this "Returns the smallest (closest to negative infinity)" for? In which way value that is returned by this function is closest to negative infinity?

Comment: Yeah, if that is what they meant, then it's correct. Thanks! Because when I do look at these kind of functions I know that they will return either smaller, or same, or greater integer values. And so I thought that this statement "Returns the smallest (closest to negative infinity)" shows in which direction your number will be treated.

Comment: You are thinking about only positive numbers. What about a negative number e.g. ceil(-4.5)? So, the definition is correct if you get it in the right way.

Comment: No, I do also pay attention to negative numbers. There is same thing. They are too being treated in positive direction. So -4.5 returns -4 (positive direction). Yeah, definition is correct, my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you use the argument `4.5`, and you want a number that is  "*greater than or equal to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer*".

There are lots of numbers that match those criteria: `5`, `6`, `7`, `100`, `2000`, ....

The **smallest** of those (closest to negative infinity) is `5`; and that's what `ceil` returns. The description is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

First, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77045161/1554195) is correct, but the reason for that complicated wording is negative numbers as arguments to `ceil()`, as [Arvind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10819573/arvind-kumar-avinash) mentioned in his comment.

Typically, we think left and right directions from 0 on the number line.

`ceil( 4.5 )` returns `5`, as we all expect without reading the documentation. But what is the result for `ceil( -4.5 )`? When we move on the number line towards negative infinity, the smallest number which is bigger than -4.5 is -4.0 which is the result of `ceil( -4.5 )`.